# how to process input with AVAudioEngine manual rendering mode?

Tags: ios, macos, avaudioengine

I'm having trouble getting `AVAudioEngine` manual rendering working when processing input. It's easy to get it working when there's no input node and audio comes from a player node.

Here's the code I've got, which can be pasted into a test:

```
- (void)testManualRendering {

    auto engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

    auto format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100.0
                                                                 channels:2];

    auto inputBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format
                                                     frameCapacity:1024];

    auto abl = inputBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList;
    XCTAssert(abl != NULL);
    XCTAssertEqual(abl->mNumberBuffers, 2);

    [engine connect:engine.inputNode to:engine.mainMixerNode format:format];

    NSError* error;
    [engine enableManualRenderingMode:AVAudioEngineManualRenderingModeOffline
                               format:format
                    maximumFrameCount:1024 error:&error];
    XCTAssertNil(error);
    XCTAssert([format isEqual:engine.manualRenderingFormat]);
    NSLog(@"manualRenderingFormat: %@", engine.manualRenderingFormat);

    auto success = [engine.inputNode setManualRenderingInputPCMFormat:format
                                                           inputBlock:^const AudioBufferList * _Nullable(AVAudioFrameCount inNumberOfFrames) {
        XCTAssert(abl->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize <= inNumberOfFrames * sizeof(float));
        XCTAssert(abl->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize <= inNumberOfFrames * sizeof(float));
        return abl;
    }];
    XCTAssert(success);

    [engine startAndReturnError:&error];
    XCTAssertNil(error);

    auto outputBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format
                                                      frameCapacity:1024];
    XCTAssertNotNil(outputBuffer);

    XCTAssert(engine.isInManualRenderingMode);
    auto status = [engine renderOffline:32 toBuffer:outputBuffer error:&error];
    if(status == AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusInsufficientDataFromInputNode) {
        printf("manual rendering failed: AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusInsufficientDataFromInputNode\n");
    }
    XCTAssertEqual(status, AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusSuccess);

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
    XCTAssertNil(error);
}
```

I'm getting `AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusInsufficientDataFromInputNode` but the input buffer has plenty of data. What am I missing? Having trouble finding example code for this.

Answer (score 3):

I've mulled over this for a few afternoons, and after some playing around, I think I have a solution for your problem and some answers as to why this isn't working as you're expecting.

`AVAudioEngine`'s `inputNode` defaults to `AVAudioInputNode` or the input of the system's audio interface. When the engine is in manual rendering mode, both the input and output nodes are disconnected from the audio interface, but a lot of the settings stay in place. So necessarily `hwFormat.sampleRate` must == `format.sampleRate`, otherwise the `[engine connect]` call will fail.

Because the audio interface is disconnected, we are not going to get data from the input, so we can use `setManualRenderingInput` to determine how we are supplying data. We can ask `[engine renderOffline]` to render a frameCapacity, apparently however, this is not guaranteed to be == `inNumberOfFrames` value passed within our `inputBlock` it changes apparently based on the selected audio device and it's respective `sampleRate`. For the `renderOffline` call to be successful `AudioBuffer.mDataByteSize` MUST == `inNumberOfFrames * sizeof(float)` otherwise the `renderOffline` call will throw insufficient data. As we cannot ensure the value of `inNumberOfFrames` before the call to `renderOffline`, the allocation of the AudioBuffers must wait until the `inputBlock`.

I'm sure there is some stuff I've missed... but anyway... try the changes below and see if this works for you.

```
- (void)testManualRendering {

    auto engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    auto hwFormat = [engine.inputNode inputFormatForBus:0];
    NSLog(@"HW Format: %@", hwFormat);
        
    ///Note: SampleRate will have to match the systems audio interface input sample rate or engine connect will throw an error
    auto format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:[hwFormat sampleRate] channels:2];
 
    NSLog(@"Input Node: %@", [engine inputNode]);
    
    auto frameCapacity = 1024;
    
    AudioBufferList *abl = (AudioBufferList *)calloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + sizeof(AudioBuffer), 1);
    XCTAssert(NULL != abl, @"Unable to allocate memory");
    abl->mNumberBuffers = [format channelCount];
    

    XCTAssertEqual(abl->mNumberBuffers, [format channelCount]);
    
    [engine connect:engine.inputNode to:engine.mainMixerNode format:format];

    NSError* error;
    [engine enableManualRenderingMode:AVAudioEngineManualRenderingModeOffline
                               format:format
                    maximumFrameCount:frameCapacity error:&error];
    XCTAssertNil(error);
    XCTAssert([format isEqual:engine.manualRenderingFormat]);
    NSLog(@"manualRenderingFormat: %@", engine.manualRenderingFormat);

    auto success = [engine.inputNode setManualRenderingInputPCMFormat:format
                                                           inputBlock:^const AudioBufferList * _Nullable(AVAudioFrameCount inNumberOfFrames) {
        
        auto byteSize = UInt32((inNumberOfFrames) * sizeof(float));
        
        unsigned i, j;
        
        for(i=0; i<abl->mNumberBuffers; ++i){
            abl->mBuffers[i].mData = calloc(sizeof(float), inNumberOfFrames);
            XCTAssert(NULL != abl->mBuffers[i].mData, @"Unable to allocate memory.");
            abl->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = byteSize;
            abl->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1;
            
            XCTAssert( abl->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize > 0);
            XCTAssert( abl->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize >= inNumberOfFrames * sizeof(float));

            float *ptr = (float *)abl->mBuffers[i].mData;
            
            //possibly load in some random data? WHY NOT!
            for(j=0; j<inNumberOfFrames; ++j){
                *ptr = (rand() / float(RAND_MAX)) * 0.8;
                ptr++;
            }
            
        }
        
        NSLog(@"Number of input frames: %i, size of frames (bytes): %lu, buffer capacity: %i", inNumberOfFrames, inNumberOfFrames * sizeof(float), abl->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);
        
        return abl;
    }];
    XCTAssert(success);

    [engine startAndReturnError:&error];
    XCTAssertNil(error);

    auto outputBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:format
                                                      frameCapacity:frameCapacity];
    XCTAssertNotNil(outputBuffer);

    XCTAssert(engine.isInManualRenderingMode);
    auto status = [engine renderOffline:frameCapacity toBuffer:outputBuffer error:&error];
    
    if(status == AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusInsufficientDataFromInputNode) {
        printf("manual rendering failed: AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusInsufficientDataFromInputNode\n");
    }
    XCTAssertEqual(status, AVAudioEngineManualRenderingStatusSuccess);

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
    XCTAssertNil(error);
    
    //free buffers
    unsigned i;
    for(i=0; i<abl->mNumberBuffers; ++i){
        free(abl->mBuffers[i].mData);
    }
    free(abl);
}
```